# Como comparar valores de uma mesma variavel e gerar uma outra variavel que ter o resultado dessa comparação no R

Tags: r

Tenho que reproduzir essa fórmula que fiz no Excel `=SE(C2=C1;1+D1;1)` para o R, mas não sei como fazer.

Eu tenho uma base onde uma das variáveis é o cargo de funcionários, e eu preciso criar uma variável que enumere os cargos que são iguais, dessa forma:

```
Cargo (Coluna C)         Numero do Cargo (Coluna D)

Analista de BI                   1
Coordenador de Dados             1
Analista de BI                   2  
Analista de Dados                1
Analista de BI                   3
```

Eu preciso criar essa coluna `Numero do Cargo`. Como fazer isso no R?

Comment: Tem que nos dizer quais são as colunas `C` e `D` nesse exemplo de dados (que só tem 2 colunas, `A` e `B` não devem ser de certeza).

Comment: Ei, coloquei a descrição na tabela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução em uma linha com `ave` e `seq_along`.

```
dados$Numero.do.Cargo.2 <- as.integer(ave(dados$Cargo, dados$Cargo, FUN = seq_along))
```

Como pode ver, a 3ª coluna é idêntica à 2ª.

---

Este problema surge de vez em quando, a função que se segue pode ser aplicada diretamente à base e à coluna que define os grupos.

```
seq_by_group <- function(x, col){
  col <- deparse(substitute(col))
  x_col <- as.character(x[[col]])
  y <- ave(x_col, x_col, FUN = seq_along)
  as.integer(y)
}

seq_by_group(dados, Cargo)
#[1] 1 1 2 1 3
```

---

### Dados

```
dados <-
structure(list(Cargo = c("Analista de BI", 
"Coordenador de Dados", "Analista de BI", 
"Analista de Dados", "Analista de BI"), 
Numero.do.Cargo = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! A aplicação funcionou perfeitamente para solução do meu problema.